# onclick=".." on Tabbable DIV also activates on Enter Key without a key event

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering, in the below example of a Tabbable DIV, I have an **onclick** handler defined, but there is no **onkeyup/onkeydown** handler.

However pressing Enter has the same effect as actually clicking the Div. Where does this functionality come from, if I have no key handler?

To test, first focus the Div by clicking the first button, and then start from there.

```js
function handleDiv() {
  alert('Clicked');
}
```

```css
#divClickable {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnFocus" onclick="$('#divClickable').focus()">Click to focus DIV Below</button>

<div id="divClickable" tabindex="0" onclick="handleDiv()">This is a test DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behaviour for submit buttons. It's part of the accessibility requirements of modern browsers so that users who browse the web via the keyboard can still trigger events on form elements using the keyboard.

One workaround if you wanted to avoid this is to change the button to `type="button"`, but note that this will have side effects if you rely on button action submitting a parent `form` element:

```js
$('#btnFocus').click(function() {
  $('#divClickable').focus();
});

$('#divClickable').click(function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
});
```

```css
#divClickable {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnFocus" type="button">Click to focus DIV Below</button>
<div id="divClickable" tabindex="0">This is a test DIV</div>
```

Note in the example above I used unobtrusive event handlers. You should not be using `on*` event attributes as they are bad practice.